Time evolution of scalar potential using Huygens principle
Huygens principle states that every point in space acts as a source of spherical waves. The amplitude for potential (scalar and vector) will be given by $V(r,t)=f(t-r/c)/r,$ where $f$  is a function and $t$ is the current time, and $r$ is the distance from the point, and $V$ is the potential (suppose scalar potential). My objective is to show that Huygens principle also predicts the same time evolution of the potential that $V_a(x,y,z,t)$ predicts (where $V_a$ is the general function of potential as a function of space time with respect to a particular point).
Firstly, I consider that potential at a given point will be the resultant of waves from all points in space .
Secondly, I consider the ratio $V(r_1,t)/V(r_2,t-(r_2-r_1)/c)$ to be $=r_2/r_1,$ where $r_(1,2)$ denotes distances from a point. This means $V(r,t)=V_a(r-g,t-g/c).(1-g/r)$ , $g$ tends to $r,$ and this will give us the relation between the potential at that point and a point $r$ distance away.
Now, to see the evolution of the superposed function at a particular point, we must consider all points in space (with same $r$ and different $r$ from that point). The overall equation for potential at a given point is shown in the image.  All I want to prove is that $V_{tot}(0,t)=V_a(0,t)$ if $V_a$ satisfies the Laplacian equation. I end up getting the sum as 0 because of the $(1-q)$ term. So definitely, I am wrong but how can I prove the equation?



That principle is very helpful for making sense of what a wave will do next, but it is necessary to point out that your scheme necessarily has to fail: If you take it too seriously, you would have waves going backwards too, and you know that the waves only go out, never back in. i.e. you actually have half sphere, not full sphere.

@naturallyInconsistent even for single slit diffraction I am not able to predict amplitudes and intensities at different positions. Huygens principle seems very hard to be used .

You need an expanded principle the Huygens-Kirchoff principle that also considers the intial velocities. The formula can be found here (for general dimensions): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Scalar_wave_equation_in_general_dimension_and_Kirchhoff's_formulae. Note that in even dimensions the "wave-front" picture can't be upheld – the solution will always depend on the solution on the interior of the disc of radius $c\Delta t$, not just on the boundary.
